# How to create a block diagram for a script in matlab

Tags: matlab

I was wondering if I have any chance to create a logical schema(state diagram) in matlab for a script. Or if I could find any programs that would do that for me.
for something like this:

```
A=[];
n=input('Numarul de linii & coloane al matricei A: ');
for i = 1:n
for j = 1:n
str = ['Introduceti elementul de pe randul ' num2str(i) ', coloana ' num2str(j) ': '];
A(i,j) = input(str);
end
end
A
suma=0;
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        if (i+j)<=(n) && A(i,j)<0;
            suma = suma + A(i,j);
        end
    end
end
suma
```